# loop in C/Arduino

Tags: loops, arduino

I need to loop through some pins, from 2 to 7, then from 7 to 2 and again from 2 to 7 and so on.
I write the code and it works, but I think it needs some edit, I didn't know how to go from 2 to 7 again.

this is my code:

```
int pins[6] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
void setup() {
}
void loop() {
  int x = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i += x) {
    pinMode(pins[i], OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(pins[i], HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(pins[i], LOW);
    delay(500);
    if (pins[i] == 7) {x = -1;}
    if (pins[i] == 2) {x = 1;}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop function is called indefinitely, so you could use that, and simply make it a forever loop. The `i < 6` condition is not needed because you want your loop to never end.

```
#define NUM_PINS 6
int pins[NUM_PINS] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
void setup()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PINS; i++) {
    pinMode(pins[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}

int x = 1;
int p = 0;
void loop()
{
    digitalWrite(pins[p], HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(pins[p], LOW);
    delay(500);
    if (p == NUM_PINS-1) {x = -1;}
    if (p == 0) {x = 1;}
    p += x;
}
```

Comment: that was useful, I'm really grateful ^_^